# Python asyncio await on future seems to be blocking

Tags: python, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to use the below code to implement async data waiting process. Basic idea is a future is passed into `wait_on_data`, another function `set_status` will set the result for this future.

The problem is when I ran the code, it seems like **await fut** doesn't suspend task, it always reached the timeout limit, and `set_status` couldn't run concurrently to set the result.
Is this because of GIL? If it is, what can I do alternatively to achieve this?

```
    def set_status(fut):
        print("set future")
        fut.set_result((True, True))
        
    async def wait_on_data(fut):
        try:
            async with asyncio.timeout(10):
                print("waiting for future")
                await fut
                return fut.result()
        except TimeoutError:
            print("timeout for future")
            return (False, False)
       
    async def main():
        fut = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()
        result = await wait_on_data(fut)
        await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(set_status(fut))
       
        assert result == True, True
```

Comment: you wait for result, before you set result. `await` will block the async function until it's done. use `asyncio.create_task` or `asyncio.gather` to set & get result concurrent

Comment: I suggest reading more about the fundamentals of `asyncio`. You are clearly missing some key concepts. The GIL has zero to do with this because this is all done in a single thread. `async` or not, code is still executed top to bottom. As @SimonChen said, when you `await wait_on_data(fut)` you are allowing a context switch, but your `set_status` is not even scheduled at that point. So the code will just wait for `wait_on_data` to finish.

Comment: thank you @SimonChen and @ DaniilFajnberg, asyncio.gather solved the issue.